# Oracle Spatial - select objects falling within area

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, geospatial, oracle-spatial

this is probably simple to those who know (I hope!)

I have an Oracle spatial database with a geometry column containing a list of node points, in northing/easting format (if it's relevent!)

I need to select those objects which fall within a given radius of a given point.

Northings and Eastings are 1 meter apart which makes it a bit easier.

Ideally this should include objects which cross the area even if their node points fall outside it.

Is this an easy-ish query? Maybe using SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE?

The table looks like this:

```
MyTable
ID NUMBER
NAME VARCHAR2(20)
DESC VARCHAR2(50)
GEOM SDO_GEOMETRY
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways.  First, as you mentioned, [SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE](http://docs.oracle.com/shtml/A85337_01/sdo_objq.htm#875674) is a valid approach.

```
select 
    *
from center_point a
inner join target_points b
    on a.id = 1
    and sdo_within_distance( b.shape, a.shape, 'distance = 10' ) = 'TRUE'
;
```

In this case, the distance is in linear units defined by a's spatial reference.  Oracle treats the coordinates as Cartesian so you will need to make sure you have a linear coordinate system before using this operator (as opposed to angular lat/lon units).  Since you are working with northings/eastings, I think you'll be okay as long as the points you are comparing against are in the same spatial reference.

This approach uses an inner-loop to solve the query so not very efficient if you have a lot of points to compare against.  Also, Oracle Spatial is VERY picky about the order of operands in the SDO functions so you might need to play around with parameter order to find the sweetspot.  If your query runs for a long period, try switching the first and second parameter of your sdo operator.  You can also play with the order of the 'from' and 'inner join' tables using the `/*+ ORDERED */` hind after `SELECT`.

Another approach is to [buffer the geometry](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A88805_01/sdo_objg.htm#852824) and compare against the buffer.

```
select 
    *
from center_point a
inner join target_points b
    on a.id = 1
    and sdo_relate( b.shape, sdo_buffer(a.shape, 0.05 ), 'mask=anyinteract' ) = 'TRUE'
;
```

Keep in mind that whatever is in the second parameter of the SDO_RELATE (called the window) will not have a spatial index if you transform it like we are here with the buffer.

If you plan on doing this with several points, it is recommended to build a table where all of the source points are buffered.  Then create a spatial index against the buffered areas and compare that to your target points.

For example:

```
create table point_bufs unrecoverable as
select sdo_buffer (a.shape, b.diminfo, 1.35)
from centerpoint a, user_sdo_geom_metadata b
where table_name='CENTERPOINT'
  and column_name='SHAPE';

select
    a.gif,
    b.gid 
from target_points a, 
     point_bufs b
where sdo_relate(a.shape, b.shape, 'mask=anyinteract querytype=join') = 'TRUE'
;
```

NOTE: When intersecting points with polygons, you always want to polygon to be in the *window position* of the sdo_relate (which is the second parameter).  This will ensure your spatial index is used correctly.

Comment: Awesome! Is it possible to do without a join? I have 1 table which I need to check against random coordinates.

Comment: Sure, just generate the shape in the 'window' position of the sdo_relate or within_distance operator (which is the 2nd parameter).  Just be aware that when you generate a shape, you aren't using a spatial index for the search so if you begin to experience performance problems, you might consider creating a table with a spatial index to hold your geometries.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way *is* to use SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE, and that is the case irrespective of the coordinate systems used, i.e. whether they are projected or geodetic:

```
select b.*
from my_table a, my_table b
where a.id = 1
and sdo_within_distance( b.shape, a.shape, 'distance=10 unit=meter' ) = 'TRUE';
```

The order of the arguments to the spatial predicates is important: the first one is the points you are searching, the second is the "query window", i.e. the point you are searching for. Notice that you should *always* specify the unit of your distance - here 10 meters. If you don't then it will default to the unit of the coordinate system of the table you search. For geodetic data, that will always be meters. For projected data it will be the unit of your coordinate system - generally meters too, but not always. Explicitly specifying a unit lifts all ambiguities.

You could also use the buffer approach, but that makes no difference here, and is actually slower. It does not matter that the second argument to a spatial predicate is indexed or not: that index is not used. Only the index on the *first* argument is required and used.

To perform the operation on a collection of geometries - i.e. for a set of points, find the points within a set distance of each of them, then consider using the SDO_JOIN() function instead, like this to find all couple of points that are within 10 meters of each other:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
  FROM my_table a,
       my_table b,
       TABLE(SDO_JOIN(
             'MY_TABLE', 'SHAPE',
             'MY_TABLE', 'SHAPE',
             'DISTANCE=10 UNIT=METER')
       ) j
WHERE j.rowid1 = a.rowid
  AND j.rowid2 = a.rowid
  AND a.rowid < a.rowid;
```