# Oracle Spatial (Locator) - Find Polygons within a distance / radius

Tags: oracle, spatial, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to implement a function that returns all entries of my table that contains polygons (that describe areas) within a specific radius (distance). I found the function `SDO_GEOM.SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE` and read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950896/oracle-spatial-select-objects-falling-within-area).

Since this is a theoretical approach and I have no real data - and I'm not a native speaker, I'm not sure at all if this function is able to do that.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to use the SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE **operator**, not the SDO_GEOM.WITHIN_DISTANCE **function**. The first will perform a search using the spatial index on the polygons table. The second will not (and so will be very slow).

Then SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE may or may not be what you need, depending on the way you define "within a radius". If by that you mean that the closest **border** of a polygon must be within the radius, then SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE is what you need.

Let's assume you have a table AREAS (ID, GEOMETRY) and a table LOCATIONS (ID, GEOMETRY) and you want to find all areas within 10 km of point 42:

```
select a.id
from areas a, locations l
where l.id=42
and sdo_within_distance (a.geometry, l.geometry, 'distance=10 unit=km') = 'TRUE';
```

On the other hand, if you want to find polygons that are **completely contained** within the radius, then you need to construct a buffer of 10 km and use that as a search area to find the matching polygons:

```
select a.id
from areas a, locations l
where l.id=42
and sdo_inside (
  a.geometry,
  sdo_geom.sdo_buffer ( 
    l.geometry,
    10,
    0.05,
    'unit=km'
  ) 
) = 'TRUE';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `SDO_GEOM.SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE` in a `WHERE` clause to do what you want - i.e. restrict the rows based on their distance from an origin shape.